# Currently Stuck on Connecting PHP with SQL SERVER 2012 in Virtual

Tags: php, macos, sql-server-2012, xampp, virtualbox

**SUMMARY** 

I have installed sqlsrv from the terminal in my macos Mojave, and it seems to work. I can connect my database from SQL server 2012 to my mac in the terminal using

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P your_password
```

but when I want to access the database from the PHP. it says Connection could not be established.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 
    [1] => 0 
    [code] => 0 
    [2] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found
  )
)
```

So I check the file using the terminal and it's actually is there physically. But I don't understand why it still hasn't work.

**What I've tried**

I tried deleting and copying the files back, but that doesn't work 
I tried doing anything that is suggested from lots of webs yet it still hasn't worked for all the files they asked me to copy is already exists.

**The Code I Use**

```
$serverName = "ip_address";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "username", "PWD" => "password", 
"Database"=>"databasename");

$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $connection )
{
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

What I'm hoping for is that my web can access the database.

Comment: You should re-install the SQLSRV. How do you install that before?

Comment: Installed it through terminal using pecl, I have tried reinstalling it just now but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you. please advice me more on what to do.

Comment: Suggest to install it via Homebrew. `brew install msodbcsql && brew link msodbcsql`